# What is the correct language "locale" when using OpenCart

Tags: php, locale, opencart

I have been asked to set up a language extension in OpenCart.  I am currently in the process of filling out this form:
[image]

I am not 100% sure what to put in the "Locale" field.

Could somebody please help me?

Many Thanks, and Merry Christmas :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the full correct string you should use is

```
fr_CA.UTF-8,fr_FR.UTF-8,fr_CA,fr_FR,fr-fr,french
```

This is from the following extension's documentation
http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=6832

Comment: heers Jay,  I actually used a different extension but it should work I hope :)

Comment: Yeah, the extension is irrelevant really, that should cover all you need

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are in France then you probably want `fr_FR` or `fr_FR.UTF-8`.

A locale is a combination of language and region in this case `french` and `France`. The `.UTF-8` also specifies a character encoding.

Comment: By the way, see full table of ISO language codes : http://www.lingoes.net/en/translator/langcode.htm